# Time validation always return false. PHP DateTime, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, date

I'm trying to create a controller for validation for time variable date and time.
The problem is the code can validate the date and check in time correctly but always getting false value for check out time.
Every variable of `$checkOut` always ended validate as `Not Valid, Wrong Check Out Time Format`.

Update : Now I only use 2 controller here, debug_controller which extends checkerController will recieve csv file and check each row in the csv file.
If there are any invalid data format, `$result` will contain "the reason why format invalid". With this code `validateDate($id, $date, $checkIn, $checkOut)` with value of `$checkOut` that should be actually false returned false.

Weird things is when I using fewer rows of csv files, one last row actually can return true.

inside csv file

```
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06,08:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,25:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-06,13:50:32,14:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,07:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,26:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-08,07:50:34,16:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-09,07:50:35,15:00:00
198601082010089999,2018-06-10,07:30:00,15:20:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-11,07:30:01,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-12,07:30:02,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-13,07:30:03,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-14,07:30:04,15:00:30
```

first controller contains functions to check input

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DateTime;

class checkerController extends Controller {

    function validateTime($time)
    {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);
        return $d && $d->format('H:i:s') == $time;
    }

    function validateDate($id, $date, $checkIn, $checkOut)
    {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
        $valid = ($d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date);
        if ($valid == false) {
            $data = "Not Valid, Wrong Date Format";
            return $data;
        } else {
            $validCheckOut = $this->validateTime("$checkOut");
            if ($validCheckOut == false) {
                return "checkout not valid --> $checkOut";
            } else {
                return "checkout valid";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

second controller, get request csv file, inherit the parent checkerController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Storage;


class debug_controller extends checkerController {

    function index(request $request){
        $ext = $request->file('csv')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = Str::random(10).".$ext";
        $path=$request->file('csv')->storeAs('public/csv/', $filename);
        $dir = asset("storage/csv/$filename");
        $file = file("$dir");
        $arrContent = Array();
        foreach ($file as $key) {
            list($id,$date,$checkIn,$checkOut)=explode(",", $key);
            $result = $this->validateDate($id,$date,$checkIn,$checkOut);;           
            $arrtemp = array('id'=> $id, 'date' => $date, 'checkIn' => $checkIn, 'checkOut' => $checkOut, 'result' => $result);
            array_push($arrContent, $arrtemp);
        }
        foreach ($arrContent as $row) {
            echo $row['id']." | ".$row['date']." | ".$row['checkIn']." | ".$row['checkOut']." | ".$row['result']."<br><br>";
            }   
    }
}
?>
```

[image: output]

Comment: side note: get rid of bad habbit of mixing languages in the code. You got English named variables but also `($nip, $tanggal, $masuk, $keluar)`. Stick to one language (best, English)

Comment: actually all the variables is in my native language, take some time for changing all the variables to english but i will try to change it only for this post on stackoverflow.

Comment: I already changed all variables name sir @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: Is your $date parameter is in `Y-m-d` format?

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. Try to debug the result using `$data = "Not Valid, Wrong Check Out Time Format -- " . $checkOut;` so you can see what makes it wrong

Comment: I have tested your code and sample data. It works perfect. Add your view and other related code.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes $date is Y-m-d.

Comment: @vozaldi I already update with the values of $checkOut, nothing wrong with the values.

Comment: @ab_ab I will change my code to not include view later.

Comment: If you only need to check the date and time format then you may use the laravel validation. It would be much easier.

Comment: I don't know how to validate contents inside .csv file

Comment: replace "$validCheckOut = $this->validateTime("$checkOut");" with `return (DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time). " -> ". $checkout);` and show us the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within the input.

```
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06,08:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,25:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15:01,14:00:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-06,13:50:32,14:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,07:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,26:50:33,15:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-08,07:50:34,16:10:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-09,07:50:35,15:00:00
198601082010089999,2018-06-10,07:30:00,15:20:00
198601082010082030,2018-06-11,07:30:01,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-12,07:30:02,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-13,07:30:03,15:00:30
198601082010082030,2018-06-14,07:30:04,15:00:30
```

To get each value of column, I use `list($id,$date,$checkIn,$checkOut)=explode(",", $key);` to assign each column to a variable.
The problem is the last value exploded didn't have `,` for the delimiter. So even the value is exactly the same string, it always return false for some reason.
When I add commas to the last value the code can validate well. 
Here is the input with added comma last value :

```
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:15:01,14:00:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06,08:15:01,14:00:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,25:15:01,14:00:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15,14:00:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-05,08:15:01,14:00:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-06,13:50:32,14:10:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,07:50:33,15:10:00,
198601082010082030,2018-02-30,07:50:33,15:10:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-07,26:50:33,15:10:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-08,07:50:34,16:10:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-09,07:50:35,15:00:00,
198601082010089999,2018-06-10,07:30:00,15:20:00,
198601082010082030,2018-06-11,07:30:01,15:00:30,
198601082010082030,2018-06-12,07:30:02,15:00:30,
198601082010082030,2018-06-13,07:30:03,15:00:30,
198601082010082030,2018-06-14,07:30:04,15:00:30,
```